# Correlation coefficient in longitudinal data

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation, scatterplot

We are performing a longitudinal analysis over different characteristics (variables) of a single subject of analysis. Our goal is not to make any predictions, but rather analyse correlations among these different variables.
No data is ever missing, and all variables are guaranteed to have a value at a given point in time.

My questions is: shall I stick to measuring correlation ignoring time (as no prediction is required for the study), modeling  two variables' values at a given point in time as a mere observation (dot) in the scatter-plot, or should I use cross-correlation using time-series?

Comment: You can use a normalizaed cross covariance function used in time series analysis - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Time_series_analysis